# ¿Crear una matriz con las coordenadas de un triángulo en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito gráficar las coordenadas de un triángulo, es decir si un triángulo tiene de base 2 y de altura 2, y lo quiero recorrer de izquierda a derecha y de arriba hacia abajo en deltas de 0.5 en ambos ejes.

```
Generar una matriz que arroje el siguiente resultado:

[[0,0],
[0.5,0],
[1,0],
[1.5,0],
[2,0],
.
.
.
.
. etc
[2,1],
[2,1.5],
[2,2]]

si alguien pudiera ayudar, muchas gracias
```

Comment: Por favor, otarga más información con mejor redacción [¿Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Una pregunta, por que guardas tantos puntos?, un triangulo se puede dibujar con tres puntos, la altura con 2 y la base con 2, pero estos ultimos 4 puntos (altura y anchura) deberian ir por aparte del triangulo, lo otro es que para graficar podrias usar pygame, no es el framework mas especializado en ello pero sin dudas te serviria para graficar el triangulo.

Comment: Ese resultado que arrojas no te podria dar un triangulo, imagino seran los intervalos, ya que como tal esos puntos no te generarian un triangulo.

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que un triangulo nunca podra dividirse en fragmentos de a 2 iguales para ser dibujado, es decir, cuando tu tratas de dibujar un triangulo en python el punto de origen siempre es (0, 0), la cual es la **esquina superior izquierda de la ventana**, ademas, el eje de dibujo esta invertido para la Y, es decir, en la realidad Y aumenta hacia arriba y disminuye hacia abajo, mientras que en la programación esto es alrevez, Y aumenta hacia abajo y decrece hacia arriba. pero la X sigue funcionando de manera normal.

Ahora, la conclusión a la que llegue para decir **"No se puede dibujar un triangulo dividiendolo en partes iguales"**, fue por lo siguiente, si tu dibujas una triangulo cualquiera, sea rectangulo, escaleno, equilatero, etc.

Tomemos como ejemplo el equilatero que tiene todos sus lados iguales, y supongamos tambien que lo dibujas con la punta hacia arriba, bien, para poder dibujar el punto intermedio (la punta) en el medio del triangulo, hay que dividir el dibujo en un punto intermedio, donde realizas el siguiente proceso:

- te situas en el punto 0,0 esquina inferior izquierda
- como son intervalos de 0.5 en 0.5, luego te debes situar en el intervalo 0.5, 0.5, hasta aqui todo bien.
- luego seguiria el intervalo 1, 1, tambien bien, aquí estariamos situados en la punta superior del triangulo que podría dividir el triangulo en 2 ojo al siguiente paso.
- luego de la punta tendriamos que irnos al intervalo 1.5, 0.5, como 1.5 - 0.5 = 1 ya no se respeta lo de delta.
- luego seguiría 2, 0 y 2 - 0 = 2, por lo tanto tampoco se respetaria delta.
- por ultimo para cerrar el triangulo sería 0, 0 de nuevo pero ya no se respetaba delta.

ahora bien dicho esto, para poder ejecutar mi solución, debes de instalar algo llamado pygame, para instalar esta libreria debes tener instalado python y pip, asumo que los tines ya instalados así que prosigamos con la instalación de pygame, en la consola digita lo siguiente:

```
pip install wheel pygame
```

entonces aquí estaria el código solución:

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
import os, math, sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

anchoVentana = 400
altoVentana = 300
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((anchoVentana, altoVentana))
pygame.display.set_caption("Triangulo")
#color del trazado
color = (120,25,50)
anchoTrazo = 4
escala = 250

def scale(points, scaleFactor):

    scaledPoints = []

    for point in points:
        currPointX = point[0] * scaleFactor
        currPointY = point[1] * scaleFactor
        scaledPoints.append([currPointX, currPointY])

    return scaledPoints

def translatePointsToCenter(points):

    translatedPoints = []

    for point in points:
        translatedPoints.append(
            [
                (anchoVentana / 2) - (point[0] / 2), 
                (altoVentana / 2) - (point[1] / 2)
            ]
        )

    return translatedPoints

def drawTriangle(points):

    index = 0
    for point in range(len(points) - 1):
        pygame.draw.line(ventana, color, points[index], points[index + 1], anchoTrazo)
        index += 1

def genIntervalMatrix(pointList, interval, limit):

    matrix = []
    i = 0

    xdeltas = []
    ydeltas = []

    while i <= limit:

        xdeltas.append([i, 0])
        ydeltas.append([limit, i])
        i += interval

    for x in xdeltas:
        matrix.append(x)

    for y in ydeltas:
        matrix.append(y)

    return matrix

triangle = [[-0.5, -0.5],[0, 0.5],[0.5, -0.5], [-0.5, -0.5]]
triangleScaledPoints = scale(triangle, escala)
triangleTranslatedPoints = translatePointsToCenter(triangleScaledPoints)
intervalMatrix = genIntervalMatrix(triangleTranslatedPoints, 0.5, 2)

print(triangleTranslatedPoints)
print("")
print(intervalMatrix)

drawTriangle(triangleTranslatedPoints)

while True:

    for eventos in pygame.event.get():

        if eventos.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Tambien se imprimen por si acaso los puntos del triangulo ya redimensionado, si lo que quieres es que solo se imprima en consola la matriz que contiene los intervalos entonces debes quitar el print(triangleTranslatedPoints).